# What's the easiest way to convert binary data to a jpeg in a Lambda function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda

I'm rewriting an AWS Lambda function which needs to convert binary data (which is contained in a request body) back to its original jpeg format, so that it can be saved to a variable and then used by Tensorflow.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Would the code below work if I don't have a local directory to save the file in? Could I then use the image variable with tensorflow?

```
imageFile = open('image.jpeg', 'wb')
image = imageFile.write(binary) # 'binary' being the data from the request body
```

Edit:

The code in question in my function is:

```
def predict(self, image):
    results = []
    try:
        image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image, channels=3)
        image_jpg = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image_decoded)
```

But I'm getting this error: Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, or GIF

Comment: Why does it have to be a lambda function instead of a def function?

Comment: Anyway, that code isn't going to work if you don't have a writable current working directory. And it's also not going to do anything useful. First, `write` just returns how many bytes it wrote, which you don't care about. Second, whatever you were planning to do with that file (e.g., if you're using Pillow, `Image.open` it) you can almost certainly do with `binary`, or with `io.BytesIO(binary)`, just as easily (but without knowing what you're planning to do with it, nobody can show you exactly how).

Comment: did OP mean AWS Lambda?

Comment: is the request body true binary? then you should be able to pass the binary data straight through. If its base64 encoded or otherwise passed in as some kind of string you will have to do some extra decoding

Comment: @abarnert Yes, sorry it's an AWS Lambda function. I've added that detail to the question.

Comment: @avigil Will tensorflow accept binary data as is? I've been trying to find out how to convert it because I figured tensorflow would only take image file formats.

Comment: So, what makes you sure that the `image` that you pass into that function really is the bytes of a JPEG file? Where does it come from? (More specific than “a request body”...)

Comment: @abarnert I'm the one sending it in to the API so I know that it's a JPEG file.

Comment: @AndyMorgan And you know that you're sending it correctly, and that you're not reading a MIME envelope rather than its contents, and so on, because…? You've tried writing the result to a file named `image.jpg`; can you open that file in xv or Paint or whatever?

Comment: @abarnert I honestly wouldn't know where to start to check any of that. I'm sending the JPEG file via Postman. I choose POST, body, binary, and then select the file.

Comment: Again: You've written code that saves the result body to a `.jpg` file. So just take one of those `jpg` files and open it in an image viewer. That's the easiest test.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for your replies. So that the comment thread doesn't get too long it's probably best to end things here (I'd move this to a chat but my reputation is too low). I don't know how to run this program outside of my AWS Lambda function and wouldn't know how to get the binary data into the program even if I did get it to run locally. The original Github repo that I'm modifying is [here](https://github.com/abhisuri97/auto-alt-text-lambda-api). If I figure out a way to solve this I'll answer my question.